# Timer Class not Firing before End of Program

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

So i've attempted to modify the code block posted by Sriram Sakthivel here:

[C#: How to start a thread at a specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18611226/c-how-to-start-a-thread-at-a-specific-time)

```
public class Program
{
    static Boolean checkIn = false;

    public static void checkInCycle()
    {
        checkIn = SynchronousSocketClient.StartClient();

        if(checkIn == false)
        {
            // Use TimeSpan constructor to specify:
            // ... Days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
            TimeSpan span = new TimeSpan(00, 00, 30);

            //SetUpTimer(span);
            DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan triggerTime  = current.TimeOfDay + span;

            SetUpTimer(triggerTime);
        }
        if(checkIn == true)
        {

            //Do some processing 
        }



    }

    public static void SetUpTimer(TimeSpan alertTime)
    {
        //DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
        //TimeSpan timeToGo = alertTime - current.TimeOfDay;

        TimeSpan timeToGo = alertTime;
        Console.WriteLine("Checking in at: " + timeToGo);

        if (timeToGo < TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            return; //time already passed
        }
        System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running CheckIn Cycle");
            checkInCycle();

        }, null, timeToGo, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);

    }

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        checkInCycle();

        Console.WriteLine("End of Program Reached");
        Console.ReadLine();

        return 0;

    }
}
```

However instead of specifying an exact time to run at, i've attempted to add 30 mins onto the current time in an attempt to make a client service that will remain alive for x amount of minutes before attempting to connect again. Right now, for simplicity/testing sake i have it set to run checkInCycle every 30 seconds if it cant connect to the server.

Upon first check SynchronousSocketClient.StartClient(); succesfully returns false if the server is down, and will enter the if(checkIn == false) loop - however, after setting up a timer it moves on to process the rest of the main loop, and waits at the end without triggering and rescheduling a timer.

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Also I understand i could just sleep the main thread for x amount of minutes before rechecking again, but the client could be asleep for up to several hours and because of this i have heard that timers are more efficient, is this the case?

Comment: Your timer is probably getting garbage collected because it is a local variable, make it a class level variable/field.

Comment: Your trigger time should just be the `span`, don't add the time of the day to it.

Comment: My apologies. You need to keep the Timer's reference to prevent it from being garbage collected. I've updated my answer in the original post to reflect that change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because at the end of your execution of the main() method you are losing the reference to your `System.Threading.Timer`. The `new System.Threading.Timer` call does not block the main thread while it waits to run its code.

- [`System.Threading.Timer` Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Timer(v=VS.110).aspx#Anchor_4)

In the above reference (second note under *Remarks*), the documentation explains that a reference must be maintained (as with all managed code) for it not to be disposed of by the Garbage Collector.

> As long as you are using a Timer, you must keep a reference to it. As with any managed object, a Timer is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected.

The way you can keep this simple program is if you use a [`System.Threading.Monitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor(v=vs.110).aspx) and perform a `Wait()` directly after the `checkInCycle()` function call in the `main()` function. Then `Pulse()` when you want to proceed.

You may want to read up on thread synchronization or concurrency further if you are curious about any more in-depth topics on performing asynchronous calls or operating in a mutli-threaded environment.

- [Thread Synchronization Reference #1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx)
- [Thread Synchronization Reference #2](http://www.bogotobogo.com/CSharp/csharp_multithreading3.php)

*edited for clarification.

Comment: Is the Wait() and Pulse() necessary though? I mean, right now i just added a reference to the Timer outside the scope of the class as suggested, and the code just sits on ReadLine() and loops the timers. Is that bad practice for a service? Is there a more gracefull way to do this instead of having the program sit on ReadLine() in order to stop it from closing

Comment: A bad practice, no. However, the console application could close if someone accidentally hit the "enter" button. The Monitor class would require a specific intention as you would have to program the Pulse() method into some action required by the user. This sounds more like a service and as such I (personally) would expect to have clearly defined start and stop actions that I could perform. [.NET Windows Service Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the [Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4562129/andrew)'s answer, the way you modified `SetupTimer`, you should not add the current time and just pass directly the retry time. Otherwise you have to wait a couple hours :-)