# How to show a MessageBox in a interval with condition

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, timer

How can I call a MessageBox.Show command when the time is exactly 5pm in C#?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    const double interval60Minutes = 1000; // milliseconds to one hour
    System.Timers.Timer checkForTime = new System.Timers.Timer(interval60Minutes);

    string Check = null;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkForTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(checkForTime_Elapsed);
        checkForTime.Enabled = true;
    }


    public void checkForTime_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime target = new DateTime(2016, 5, 8, 11, 58, 0);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        if (target.ToString("HH:mm:ss") == now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") && (Check == null))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome Admin");
            checkForTime.Stop();
            checkForTime.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

If I put just `MessageBox.Show` without the if statement it works, but when I put a condition nothing happens. The timer won't stop I used both enabled = false and stop function.

Comment: The odds that the time matches *exactly* within 100 nanoseconds are very, very low.  Also rather a bad idea to use System.Timers.Timer, good odds that the message box disappears behind another window since the Elapsed event runs on a worker thread.  Drop a Timer from the toolbox.  Calculate the Interval so you need only one Tick.  And use NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip() to tell the user.

Comment: Look at this answer to a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/18270238/820068

Comment: why you are referring a link which is close as off topic ?

Comment: @MostafizurRahman - actually the question is closed because of a user not demonstrating minimal understanding, not because it is off-topic.  Hopefully it will someday get addressed, but I understand the mods have a lot more to deal with on stackoverflow than we do over in workplace.  However, the answer I provided the link to is almost exactly what I was going to answer with, so it is, IMO, a duplicate.

Comment: use my update I have added how to stop timer

Comment: @MostafizurRahman For some reason I can't access the checkForTime.Stop(); in the method checkForTimeElapsed

Comment: put your timer in global scope see my update

Comment: @MostafizurRahman brother I used your answer but it wont stop the timer. It keep showing the messagebox. Please see my updated question..

Comment: ok let me check again

Comment: @Ryze2 brother I have just check your code and its working fine here, please look carefully if the is problem in somewhere else

Comment: @MostafizurRahman so the messagebox only shows up once?

Comment: move your target time outside the `checkForTime_Elapsed` method because both target time and present time is initialize inside the `checkForTime_Elapsed` so everytime it true, for this messegebox will show up every time, move outside then it will only show whne the time match

Comment: your `ToString("01:05")` code is wrong I going to edit it

Comment: @MostafizurRahman I put all the code in the question box please tell me what I did wrong thank you brother

Comment: got it you are stoping the timer insdie the callback function for that you have to set `checkForTime.AutoReset = false;` in your code see my latest update

Comment: Okay thank you brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this, this code will check if your target time and present time is same or not if same then it will run the MessageBox

```
if (target.ToString("HH:mm:ss") == now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"))
   {
       MessageBox.Show("It's Time");
   }
```

use

```
checkForTime.Stop();
```

where you want to stop the timer

to access the timer from another method put your timer in the global scope

```
    const double interval60Minutes = 1000; // milliseconds to one hour
    System.Timers.Timer checkForTime = new System.Timers.Timer(interval60Minutes);

    string Check = null;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        checkForTime.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(checkForTime_Elapsed);
        checkForTime.Enabled = true;
        checkForTime.AutoReset = false;
    }


    public void checkForTime_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime target = new DateTime(2016, 5, 8, 11, 58, 0);
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        if (target.ToString("HH:mm:ss") == now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") && (Check == null))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome Admin");
            checkForTime.Stop();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Updated time format to `HH:mm:ss` to be simpler.

Comment: reason for downvote please it will improve my answer

Comment: Directly comparing times like that is sketchy. Comparing whole seconds will probably work, but there's no guarantee that the program/system won't choke and miss the time. A better way is to check whether the current time is past or equal to a certain time. Also converting to strings and comparing seems like a waste of resources.